# How can I remove a duplicate startup entry?

Tags: boot

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro and I recently noticed that WhatPulse is starting twice (apparently) on startup:

[image]

I did most things that come to mind, like check if it exists in the startup folder, but I can't find the "second" place it's starting from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look with [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) - it might be in both a user-specific and system-wide startup location. You could also manually go through the registry, but this is far easier.

Also, check to see if it's actually starting two instances - see if there's two copies running on the Details tab of Task Manager. It may be that the Startup tab is simply misreporting.

Comment: I think Autoruns is probably the best solution for most instances, although it's giving me some trouble still in this case. Thank you!